# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\fps.php on line 117

Tags: php, html, curl

Hi I've researched this problem here pretty extensively and on other sites and have not found my answer. First off let me start by saying I am trying to learn this all on my own so any advice is welcome.

I am trying to curl a website where one of our applications is hosted on. I am attempting to dump it's contents into a div for a sales demo and I am having difficulty doing so. Since it is a Https protocol an simple iFrame will not do the job. Again this is our company's owned app but hosted on a social network site.

Here is my code at the head level:

```
<?php
    // Defining the basic cURL function
    function file_get_html($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.a_website.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
    $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
    // var_dump($data);
    curl_close($ch); // Closing cURL
    return $data;   // Returning the data from the function
    }
  ?>
```

I've already tried the var_dump($data) suggestion which I've seen as an answer for similar posts such as mine but I being a newbie don't understand what that actually does. I know from reading other posts here and elsewhere that "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\fps.php on line 117" is not and error but a warning/notice.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Attempting to output content to:

```
<div>
  <?php
    // Dump contents (without tags) from HTML
    echo file_get_html("www.facebook.com/appcenter/sgprivacy")->html;
  ?>
</div>
```

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: `$data` is a string, not an object.  Take off the `->html` and it will work.

Comment: Which line is line 117? What did you get when you used var_dump?

Answer (score 0):

There error is accurate here is the problem:

```
<div>
  <?php
    // Dump contents (without tags) from HTML
    echo file_get_html("www.facebook.com/appcenter/sgprivacy")->html; // this here
  ?>
</div>
```

The value `file_get_html` returns is not an object, it is a string. Change it to this:

```
echo file_get_html("www.facebook.com/appcenter/sgprivacy");
```

if you want to remove all html tags, you can use the [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

```
$data = file_get_html("www.facebook.com/appcenter/sgprivacy");
echo strip_tags($data);
```